# Is there a way to copy an activity to another database?

Tags: brightway

I would like to create a copy of an activity and move it in another database.

I can see two solutions:

**Option 1** - Use the method `.copy()` of my activity and then to change the database of the copy. The problem is that I cannot figure how to move an activity from one database to another or even if it is possible.

**Option 2** - Re-create an activity in the destination database that contains the data of the activity to copy. Although it is not difficult, I find this option way less elegant.
Below is an implementation of option 2.

```
def copy_activity(activity, target_database=None, target_name=None):
    """
        Copy an activity to another database

        Args:
            activity: Activity to copy
            target_database (str):
                Name of the database in which to copy the activity default is the database of the activity
            target_name (str): Name of the copy, default is the name of the activity
    """

    if (target_database is None) and (target_name is None):
        raise ValueError('You must specify at least a target database or a target name')

    db_name = target_database or activity.key[0]
    db = bw.Database(db_name)

    activity_copy = db.new_activity(activity.key[1])

    for attribute in activity:
        activity_copy[attribute] = activity[attribute]

    for exchange in activity.exchanges():
        if exchange.input == exchange.output:
            activity_copy.new_exchange(input=activity_copy, output=activity_copy)
        else:
            activity_copy.new_exchange(input=exchange.input, output=activity_copy)

    activity_copy.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the database of an activity with `my_activity['database'] = 'something'`. You don't need to save afterwards.

Functionality in the source code [here](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/blob/master/bw2data/backends/proxies.py#L200), tests [here](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-data/blob/master/tests/activity_proxy.py#L102).

Comment: Thank you @Chris Mutel, this was so obvious that I didn't find it !